# Replacing variables names dynamically like string parts

Tags: arrays, swift, string, variables

I'd like to optimise my code using a single function to process multiple possibilities depending on the situation: here it is different currencies.

I know how to do it when I use strings with the `\(something)` syntax and I'd like something similar for variables.

Here is my current situation for USD:

```
if WalletViewController.currencyUSD == true {
    if CurrentDifferenceFunctions.buyOrSellBitcoinUSD == 1 {
        if let lastBitcoinBuyPrice = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "lastBitcoinBuyPrice\(currentCurrency)") as? Double {
            CurrentDifferenceFunctions.savedBitcoinPrice = lastBitcoinBuyPrice
        }
    } else if CurrentDifferenceFunctions.buyOrSellBitcoinUSD == 2 {
        if let lastBitcoinSellPrice = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "lastBitcoinSellPrice\(currentCurrency)") as? Double {
            CurrentDifferenceFunctions.savedBitcoinPrice = lastBitcoinSellPrice
        }
    }
}
```

How can I replace `USD` everytime it appears by another currency when needed and then be able to use the same function for different currencies? Would using arrays help here?

I have a few dozens cryptos and as many currencies to process, any help would be gold!

PS: I'm sorry about the redundant `WalletViewController.currencyUSD == true` but I like to keep my work literal until I fully understand the logic.

Comment: Look at dictionaries.  Basically, they are the answer when you want to use a key to reference associated information at run time.

Comment: Not related but consider that there is `double(forKey:` in `UserDefaults` which returns always a non-optional.

Comment: Thank you Philip, what would be the logic? Replacing the single variable by something that would be a corresponding dictionary key depending on the situation?

Comment: @vadian thanks! noted and applied